# PyAutoGUI charmap install error (Windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.6, pyautogui

When installing **pyautogui** package I got this error:

```
Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/70/c5d340fadb06106135b7fe9677fc6d275f3cd7f7e6f896316c4cfe6c022c/PyAutoGUI-0.9.37.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ogi36fze\pyautogui\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        long_description = fh.read()
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 290: character maps to <undefined>
```

It is an error with "charmap". What should I do to install that package?
I tried `chcp 65001` in the command line, but it is not that simple I think.

I am using **Python 3.6** (x64), **Windows 10** and **PyCharm**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in PyAutoGUI 0.9.38.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with PyAutoGUI version **0.9.37**. You must install **0.9.36** to solve that problem.